# Dual boot Windows 8.1 & Kubuntu 16.04 - after booting into Windows, I always then get grub rescue when I try to boot Kubuntu

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi

Hardware config: Gigabyte MB with AMD 3.5 Ghz 6-core CPU, 16GB ram, 1 DVD writer, 1 sata 2TB (P0), and 1 sata 500GB (P1) drive.

Windows 8.1 on 2TB drive in a 800 GB partition (GPT format), Ubuntu on 500GB drive (2 partitions, / and /home, configured as MBR).

Ubuntu was installed last and is the default OS. Both OSes boot EFI.

However after booting into Windows and then re-booting back to try Ubuntu I end up at a `grub rescue>` screen (every time). This used to work all the time. Gotten to the point where I am going to try VMware for running Windows (only used for games) versus Linux (used for everything else). Windows has been configured to not use fast boot and has been virus scanned (a lot of cleanup was involved with Malwarebytes and ccleaner).

Open to suggestions on what to look for short of re-installing Windows (too many games/logins to save).

Tried boot-repair and it says fixed but doesn't do it.

Have done GRUB re-install multiple times and it has not stayed fixed.

Gotten to the point where I can't boot Windows because it kills Linux.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What are the error when sustem enters GRUB at reboot ? Any text above the prompt ?

Comment: Shows up @ grub rescue prompt saying missing grub.

Comment: further research show the /boot directory actually being located on sda2 which is the efi partition (I think)

Comment: The Windows data partition as a VM image works fine